# How can i access a nodeJS variable in ejs views in a sails project?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My LoginController.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  getAuthorizationLink: function (req, res) {
    res.send({
      authorization_link: sails.config.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL
    })
  }
}
```

I need to redirect to the authorization_link when a button is clicked

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
  <button id="authenticate" class="btn btn-primary">Authenticate   Page</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("authenticate").onclick = function () {
     ...
    };
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are using .ejs, use <%= authorization_link =%> for accessing passed argument

Comment: yes i am using .ejs..but its not working with the above solution

Comment: I don't know sails very well, but since it's built on top of Express, try using `res.render` instead of `res.send`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are looking to mix server-side (EJS) & client-side JS code.

It is possible, makes sense to do sometimes but it is not clean.
Once you understand you are doing this. Variable can be passed and accessed.

Using EJS, write JS code for client side e.g.

```
var auth_link = '<%= authorization_link %>';
```

this line will become something like below for client-side JS

```
var auth_link = 'https://fb.com/login';
```

Now you can use `auth_link` in client-side JS as required

Also, check [res.view](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-view) for responding with HTML page